# Parallelization inside a module: Proper use of local variables

Tags: parallelization, scoping

I have the following `Module` which includes a `ParallelDo` call. Unfortunately, `ParallelDo` is not using the local variable:

```
Clear[a];
foo[a_] = a;
nmax = 3;
tmpMat = IdentityMatrix[nmax];
SetSharedVariable[tmpMat]
a = 0;
foo2[a0_] := Module[{a = a0},
  ParallelDo[tmpMat[[n1, n2]] = foo[a], {n1, 1, nmax}, {n2, 1, nmax}
   ];
  tmpMat
  ]
```

Now `foo2[1]` returns

```
{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}
```

instead of

```
{{1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}}
```

when `Do[]` is used. How to change the property of `a` to make the parallelized code use the *local* variable `a` and not the global one which is set to zero?

Comment: If you don't need to update `a` in the code, does using `With` instead of `Module` work?

Comment: @march: It's a oversimplified version of a much more complex module. It has to be a module.

Comment: There's a bigger problem: `tmpMat` is not shared between parallel kernels, so you can't modify it. You can make it shared (`SetSharedVariable`), but that tends to destroy any speed benefits brought by parallelization. Effective parallelization in Mathematica requires that the parallel threads not try to access the same data at the same time.  Why don't you just use `ParallelTable`, or better: `ParallelMap`, to compute the elements *first*, then assign them to a matrix only after the computation is done.

Comment: Is it possible for you to use `SetDelayed` when defining `foo`?

Comment: That should be "it will destroy benefits brought by parallelization, *unless* `foo` takes extra long to evaluate".  About `With` vs `Module`: you can always place a smaller `With` *inside* of a `Module`. I can't at this moment see any reason that would truly prevent you from using `With`. Please explain, preferably through an example, if you disagree.

Comment: In fact you can even use `With[{a=a}, foo[a]]` to inline the value of `a`. Try it by writing `Hold` instead of `foo`.

Comment: @Szabolcs: Indeed, I'm using `SetSharedVariable`, I only forgot to put it in the above text. It seems to be really bad software design if putting `tmpMat` as shared slows down the code since there is no race-condition at all when accessing array elements in the way `[...,{n1,1,nmax},{n2,1,nmax}]` (I'm thinking about e.g. array access in C using openMP)

Comment: @Szabolcs: I'm not searching for a *workaround*. There has to be a solution for the case of a module.

Comment: Mathematica and C are very different. If you try to program in Mathematica the way you would in C, brace yourself for a lot of frustration. OpenMP uses a shared memory model; Mathematica doesn't. Each model comes with its advantages and disadvantages—for example you cannot use OpenMP across multiple computers. Consider reading up on this before you call it bad design.

Comment: What I suggested is not a workaround. It is the appropriate ways to do it. I tested what happens with `Module`. The `Module` variable *is* properly picked up (i.e. I cannot reproduce what you said you saw).  I suspect that Edmund is right and you made a mistake when defining `foo` with `=` instead of `:=`. The symbol `a` must already have had a value at the point of definition.

Comment: Why should using `=` be a problem. I Clear the value of `a` before defining `foo`?

Comment: However, using `Module` this way is a very very bad idea. Why? Because every run of your program will distribute (`DistributeDefinitions`) a different localized version of `a` (i.e. `a$1`, `a$2`, ...) to the parallel kernels. These never get cleared.  You effectively created a memory leak.  Always keep in mind that parallel threads are actually completely separate processes, and any data sharing must be explicit at some level. Never use a `Module` variable inside of a `Parallel*` function this way.

Comment: @Szabolcs: I see, thank you!

Comment: You are right, `=` vs `:=` should not cause this (even though it does). I suspect a bug. Give me a bit of time.

Comment: This behaviour of DistributeDefinitions really bothers me, so I am going to ask Wolfram Support about it. I will let you know what they said, and whether they confirmed it as a bug.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are multiple issues here. Let us take them one by one.

#### Why do you get `0` as the output?

There is a quirk in how `DistributeDefinition` works. To me, this looks like a bug ...  Let me show it through a smaller example that isolates the problem.

Let's define a function in a fresh kernel using [`Set`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Set.html) instead of [`SetDelayed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetDelayed.html), then distribute its definitions, and finally check what definitions are present on the subkernels.

```
Quit[]
foo[a_] = a;
DistributeDefinitions[foo];
ParallelEvaluate[Print@Definition["foo"]]
```

> `foo[a_]=a`
>
> `foo[a_]=a`
>
> `foo[a_]=a`
>
> `foo[a_]=a`

Everything is as one would expect it.  But now let's tweak the code a bit ...

```
Quit[]
foo[a_] = a;    
a = 0; (* set a value for 'a' before distributing foo's definition *)    
DistributeDefinitions[foo];
```

What's the definition on the main kernel?

```
Definition[foo]
```

> `foo[a_] = a`

What's the definition on the subkernels?

> `foo[a_]=0`
>
> `foo[a_]=0`
>
> `foo[a_]=0`
>
> `foo[a_]=0`

Oops! That's now what I expected, and it's not what it should be: it's not the same as on the main kernel. `a` got evaluated during the distribution process.

I see the same behaviour in all versions between 9.0–11.0, and I find it very disturbing.  There are legitimate reasons for using `Set` instead of `SetDelayed`, and there are legitimate reasons for using the resulting function in parallelized code.  Therefore I would consider this a bug.

**What should you do then?**

- If you don't need to, don't use `=`. Use `:=` instead, which prevents the RHS from evaluating during distribution.
- If you need to use `=`, don't define a global `a`.
- If you both need to use `=` and define a global `a`, then manually evaluate `DistributeDefinitions[foo]` *and* `LaunchKernels[]` *before* you set the global `a`; or evaluate `Block[{a}, DistributeDefinitions[foo]; LaunchKernels[]]` to temporarily unset `a` during distribution. The point is not to allow `ParallelDo` or other parallel functions do the distribution automatically—preemptively distribute them in advance.

  Be sure to launch the kernels right after distributing the definitions. `DistributeDefinitions` only registers a symbol for distribution. Actual distribution happens only upon kernel launch.  Unfortunately, kernel launch is hard to control and may be triggered by mayny things. For example, kernels that die for some reason get automatically re-launched mid-computation. For this reason, this third workaround isn't fully robust. Better stick to the first two whenever you can.

*Obviously, these are only workarounds.*

#### Does `Module` work with parallel functions?

This works:

```
Module[{a = 1},
 ParallelDo[Print[a], {4}]
]
```

Each kernel on my machine prints `1`.  But please do not do this because it effectively creates a memory leak.  `Module` "localizes" symbols through renaming. 
Each evaluation of the `Module` creates a new symbol with a name like `a$123`.  These symbols are removed immediately when a `Module` exits. But if we use them in a parallel function, they get automatically copied (distributed) to all subkernels, and remain there.  Therefore this code effectively has a memory leak.  After three runs of the code, I see this on the subkernels:

```
ParallelEvaluate[Information["Global`a$*"]]
```

> `a$2695 a$4410 a$4421`
>
> `a$2695 a$4410 a$4421`
>
> `a$2695 a$4410 a$4421`
>
> `a$2695 a$4410 a$4421`

For similar reasons, also do not use `Block` this way. It will mess up the bookkeeping information about distributed symbols.

#### If `Block` and `Module` variables shouldn't be used in parallel functions, what can I use instead?

The usual solution would be to inline the value of the symbol. This can be done using `With`.

```
With[{a=1},
  ParallelDo[foo[a], ...]
]
```

It replaces `a` with its value in `ParallelDo`, so `ParallelDo` never even sees the symbol `a` (only its value).  This approach does not have a performance hit because the value needs to be copied to each subkernel either way.  Subkernels are separate processes, and do not share any memory.  Things like `SetSharedVariable` simulate shared memory by always evaluating and setting that variable on the main kernel. This has the drawback that all those callbacks can reduce performance significantly. It is only worth using this if you know that these callbacks still take less time than the evaluation of `foo`.